# Empty nested object with partial update on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've the following document indexed in ElasticSearch

```
{
  "myObj":{
     "name": "test",
     "elements": {
        "val": 1
     }
  }
}
```

I want to do a partial update to empty the nested attribute `elements` so I should be `elements": {}`; So I tried to send a partial update:

`POST /entities/_doc/1/_update`

```
{
   "doc" : {
      "myObj":{
         "elements": {}  
      }
   }
}
```

But this does nothing and the document keeps untouched. How can I empty a nested object in a document using partial updates ?

Comment: Is it just an object or nested object?

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with ElasticSearch terms but it is a simple attribute of my object. Like `myObj.elements.val` and I want it to be `myObject.elements == empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to do a scripted update like this and it will work:

```
POST entities/_doc/1/_update
{
   "script" : {
      "source": """
         ctx._source.myObj.elements.clear(); 
         ctx._source.myObj.name = params.name;
      """,
      "params": {
        "name": "newTest"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to update other fields as well ? Can I do a partial update along with this script ? Because when I tried here, I got an error `Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both script and doc`

Comment: You can definitely line up several updates in the script

Comment: How can I do that ? Suppose that I want to update the `name` attribute as well on the same request.

Comment: See my updated answer (note that the three `"` are intended and that's how you can send new lines separated scripts to ES and make your scripts more readable)

Comment: Thanks @Val. It works, but it is a pain when we have a more complex object. Would be great if ES provides a way to send scripts and objects together.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set the value as `null` to empty the object completely.

```
POST /entities/_doc/1/_update
{
   "doc" : {
      "myObj":{
         "elements": null  
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the `elements` map will be null instead of empty.

Comment: @Val But does it make a difference? In any case both are same if we consider the behaviour of exists query. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sure, I'm just stating that given the requirements stated by the OP. Not sure what he does with the `elements` map next. Also, the problem is that when seeing `elements: null` you don't know if it was an object field or a normal field originally

Comment: @Val Agree to that. It totally depends how one is going to further use the object field. Thanks for your prompt reply.