# Update API Elasticsearch remove some nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine the following document into my index:

```
PUT test

POST test/_doc/1
{
  "name": "old_name",
  "data": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "lol": "alright"
  },
  "collections": ["first", "second"]
}
```

I would like to transform my document to:

```
{
    "name" : "new_name",
    "data": {
      "foo": "lol"
    },
    "collections": ["first", "second"]
}
```

Problem is, if I use the update API like the following:

```
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
    "doc" : {
        "name" : "new_name",
        "data": {
          "foo": "lol"
        }
    }
}
```

The document becomes

```
{
  "name": "new_name",
  "data": {
    "foo": "lol",
    "lol": "alright"
  },
  "collections": [
    "first",
    "second"
  ]
}
```

And the `"lol"` attribute have not been removed.

I only want my request to remove all attributes nested in the `data` key to be removed if not present in the update request, but I want other attributes to stay (like the `collections` key).

I know that the ElasticSearch documentation says:

> The update API also supports passing a partial document, which will be
>   merged into the existing document (simple recursive merge, inner
>   merging of objects, replacing core "keys/values" and arrays)

**Is their something easy I could do to respond to my problem, should I make multiple requests?**

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351050/4604579